Empty values in JSON dict from javascript
I have JavaScript at Front:
var mix = {
    methods: {
        signIn () {
            const username = document.querySelector('#login').value
            const password = document.querySelector('#password').value
      var dict = {}
      dict['username']=username
            this.postData('/api/sign-in/', JSON.stringify(dict))
                .then(({ data, status }) => {
                    location.assign(`/`)
                })
                .catch(() => {
                    alert('Error auth')
                })
        }
    },
    mounted() {
    },
    data() {
        return {}
    }
}

And when I send POST query like
{"username": "aa"}
I receive dict like:
{'{"username":"aa"}': ''}
As you can see value is empty, all data set as key. What can be a problem?
Thx.

It sounds like the call to JSON.stringify is unnecessary?  this.postData may be expecting an object, not a string.

As an aside... You'll want to get in the habit of (1) consistently indenting your code and (2) terminating statements with semicolons.  Both are very common sources of bugs.  Not necessarily this bug, but it's a habit worth building.

const username = document.getElementById('login').value; const password = document.getElementById('password').value; ?
